# iPhone: [subview release] removes my subview from the display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, subview

I have these two pieces of code. The first one works perfectly:

```
UIView *tmp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 60.0f, 296.0f, 44.0f)];
[self.dynamicView addSubview:tmp];
[tmp release];
```

The second one is pretty much the same, but the view doesn't show up.

```
CommentBox *commentBox = [[CommentBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 296.0f, 44.0f)]; 
[self.dynamicView addSubview:commentBox];
[commentBox release];   // Why does this remove the view?
```

If I remove the `[commentBox release]` the view surprisingly appears. But I don't see a different between these two code snippets.

The init for the CommentBox looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Load the nib:
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommentBox" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing weird things in `-initWithFrame:`. I'm not 100% sure that it's causing the problem you report, but I'm pretty sure it's:

- wrong; and
- causing a memory leak.

I don't think replacing a view object with something dearchived from a nib in its `-init…` methods is a good idea. Either load the nib from a controller class, or have your initialiser load the object's *subviews* from the nib without replacing `self`.

Comment: Thanks Graham. I posted my new solution below.

Answer (score 3):

After thinking about Graham's answer I came up with the following solution:

1. I drag a new UIView (-> lets call it sub UIView) in Interface Builder in my main UIView
2. I give this sub UIView the correct size (because I cannot resize the main UIView, which is always 320x460)
3. I drag all my other elements in this sub UIView (so that all elements are attached to my sub UIView)
4. I give my sub UIView a tag number (Interface Builder -> View Attributes), e.g. "300"
5. In the code I do now the following within my `-initWithFrame:`

   NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommentBox" owner:self options:nil];
   UIView *subView = [[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0] viewWithTag:300];
   [self addSubview:subView];

Hope that helps.

---

**Update:**

I just had another idea of doing it. Instead of the tag numbers you can also create a `IBOutlet UIView *viewHolder` in the `CommentBox` class and set the outlet in IB. Then in the `initWithFrame:` I do the following:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommentBox" owner:self options:nil];
[self addSubview:self.viewHolder];
```